# Thunderbolt dock statation power charging

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, charging, power, magsafe

There are two types of dock stations on the market:

1. Docks use external MagSafe adapter to charge MBP. 
   (MagSafe should be bought additional from Apple).
2. Docks with only Thunderbolt connection to MBP.

With first one power supplying is clear.
How does second type can charge MBP?

**Is it possible to charge laptop through thunderbolt without MagSafe?**

P.S. Consider MacBook Pro 2014-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Thunderbolt port does not supply power to the laptop. The only way to provide power is through the MagSafe connector.

Answer (score 1):

The second type simply does not charge the MBP.

It is not possible to charge the laptop (MBP) through the Thunderbolt port.